# C++ WinApi CreateProcess Unable To Create Child Process With Environment Block

Tags: c++, winapi, createprocess

I need help with creating child process inheriting the new temporary Path environment variable then using the child process, it will run the process inside new folder specified in the Path.

Example, I add C:\Test into Path environment variable,and then i wan't to run a program by using cmd.exe as the child process

I'm having problem to create process by using the line below,it will pop up message unable to run the child process

```
Utilities::createProcess(_T("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"),_T(""),txtbuff);
// txtbuff is a WCHAR with size of 4096
// it contains the concatenation of _T("Path=C:\\Test;\0"); and pszOldPath
// pszOldPath get its value from GetEnvironmentVariable(_T("PATH"), pszOldPath,4096);
// The concantenated string will have the form of _T("Path=path1\0path2\0....\0\0");
```

If i pass NULL as my environment block,I'll be able to execute my child process but it won't inherit the new Path environment variable thus cmd.exe cannot run a program that is not specified in current path environment

```
Utilities::createProcess(_T("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"),_T(""),NULL);
```

This is my code:

```
// Utilities.h
namespace Utilities
{
    bool createProcess(LPCWSTR filename,LPWSTR arg,LPTSTR envpath)
    {
        DWORD dwRet;
        LPTSTR pszOldVal;
        TCHAR pszDest[BUFSIZE] = _T("");
        pszOldVal = (LPTSTR) malloc(BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR));
        if(envpath != NULL)
        {
            dwRet = GetEnvironmentVariable(_T("PATH"), pszOldVal, BUFSIZE);
            if(!dwRet)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL,_T("Get environment variables failed."),_T("Error"),MB_OK);
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                StringCchCat(pszDest,BUFSIZE,_T("Path="));
                StringCchCat(pszDest,BUFSIZE,envpath);
                StringCchCat(pszDest,BUFSIZE,_T(";\0"));
                StringCchCat(pszDest,BUFSIZE,pszOldVal);
                //MessageBox(NULL,pszDest,_T("Environtment Variables"),MB_OK);
            }
        }
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb= sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
        if(!CreateProcess(filename,arg,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,pszDest,NULL,&si,&pi))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,_T("Unable to create process."),_T("Error"),MB_OK);
            return false;
        }
        //WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        free(pszOldVal);
        return true;
    }
}
// Main.cpp
// At Wnd Proc
LRESULT CALLBACK(......)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(wParam)
    {
        case ID_TEST:
            Utilities::getDlgText(hWnd,ID_INPUT_CPP,txtbuff);
            if(_tcscmp(txtbuff, _T("")) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL,_T("Please make sure you select folder."),_T("Error"),MB_OK);
                break;
            }
            // Environtment variable"MyVar=MyValue\0MyOtheVar=MyOtherValue\0\0"

// This is where Im having problem right now
            Utilities::createProcess(_T("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe"),_T(""),txtbuff,NULL);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Really need someone to enlighten me with the answer

Comment: What error code does [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) return? Without this your just guessing that the new environment is the issue.

Comment: Also [`StringCchCat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647518%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is not suitable for manipulating character buffers with embedded nulls: the next call will treat the first `\0` it finds as the point to start writing new characters.

Comment: GetLastError return 0. I'll try change StringCch into something else.

Comment: Managed to fixed it..  
I checked back the [Changing Environment Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682009%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article and instead of passing the null terminated string to lpEnvironment, i used

    `SetEnvironmentVariable(_T("PATH"),pszDest);`

then

    `CreateProcess(filename,arg,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,&si,&pi)`

Thus,the null terminated string problem solved. Now I just need to change the single backslash into double backslash or a forward slash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Utilities.h
namespace Utilities
{
    bool createProcess(LPCWSTR filename, LPWSTR arg, LPWSTR envpath)
    {
        std::vector<WCHAR> oldPath;
        std::vector<WCHAR> newPath;
        DWORD dwOldLen = 0;

        if(envpath != NULL)
        {
            DWORD dwLen = GetEnvironmentVariable(L"PATH", NULL, 0);
            if (dwLen) {
                oldPath.resize(dwLen);
                dwOldLen = GetEnvironmentVariable(L"PATH", oldPath.data(), dwLen);
                if(dwOldLen + 1 != dwLen)
                {
                    MessageBox(NULL,_T("Get environment variables failed."),_T("Error"),MB_OK);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            size_t newLen = dwOldLen + wcslen(envpath) + 8; //8 for "path=" ";" and double null terminating
            newPath.resize(newLen);
            std::fill(newPath.begin(), newPath.end(), 0);
            memcpy(newPath.data(), L"Path=", 5 * 2);
            memcpy(newPath.data() + 5, oldPath.data(), dwOldLen * 2);
            memcpy(newPath.data() + 5 + dwOldLen, L";", 2);
            memcpy(newPath.data() + 6 + dwOldLen, envpath, wcslen(envpath) * 2);
        }
        STARTUPINFO si;
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb= sizeof(si);
        ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
        if(!CreateProcess(filename,arg,NULL,NULL,NULL,CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,newPath.data(),NULL,&si,&pi))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL,_T("Unable to create process."),_T("Error"),MB_OK);
            return false;
        }
        //WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why memcpy size for wchar needs to be multiplied by 2 because wchar holds 2 bytes for each or something?  
I'm gonna start learning on bytes stuff in a week.

Comment: @D13:Yes, wchar is 2 bytes.